# ExtJS Grid Paging Toolbar displaying wrong number of pages

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

Paging tool bar shows correct number (page 1 of 3) initially. But, when next button is clicked it shows a different  number such as (page 1 of 657). I suppose the 657 number is the total number of items in the store for all the data which sums up to 657 pages.

The grid code is as follows:

```
Ext.define('MyProject.view.transaction.List', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.GridPanel',
alias: 'widget.transactionList',

title: 'Transactions',

initComponent: function() {
    this.store = 'Transactions';
    this.columns = [
         { header: 'posting_sta_ind', dataIndex: 'posting_sta_ind', flex: 0 }
        , { header: 'transaction_code', dataIndex: 'transaction_code', flex: 0 }
        , { header: 'transaction_amt', dataIndex: 'transaction_amt', flex: 0 }
        , { header: 'item_desc', dataIndex: 'item_desc', flex: 0 }
        , { header: 'is_returnable', dataIndex: 'is_returnable', flex: 0 }
        , { header: 'serial_no', dataIndex: 'serial_no', flex: 0 }
        , { header: 'value_date', dataIndex: 'value_date', flex: 0 }
        , { header: 'booking_date', dataIndex: 'booking_date', flex: 0 }
    ];
    this.viewConfig = {
        stripeRows: true
    };

    this.dockedItems = [{
        xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
        store: 'Transactions',
        dock: 'bottom',
        displayInfo: true
    }];

    this.callParent(arguments);
}});
```

How do I solve this problem?

The below method pulls the transactions store for the particular account id that is passed.

```
transactionTabClick: function () {
    var controller = this;
    controller.getAccountsStore().each(function (record) {
        controller.getTransactionsStore().load({
            params: TasoDesktop.Util.authorize({
                account_id: record.get('account_number')
            })
        });
    });
    controller.getTransactionTab().un('activate', controller.transactionTabClick, controller);
},
```

The response I am getting back before clicking the next or refresh button.

```
{"total":1,"transactions":[{"is_overdraft_fee":"NO","dda_rej_cd_domain_item_id":"22","is_overdraft_fee_dda_dflt":"Y","business_dt":"2014-02-04 00:00:00.0","booking_date":null,"item_desc":"FUNDING XFER TO 000000708361407 TRN: 0190002236RA","serial_no":"0","transaction_amt":"108,879.96","detailed_desc":null,"modified_by":"SYSTEM","posting_ind":"P","is_overdraft_notice":"NO","credit_debit_flag":"D","is_returnable":"N","modified_dt":"2014-04-11 03:07:18.0","transaction_code":"327","account_id":"1085117","value_date":null,"is_paperless":"Y","bank_code":"0111","transaction_id":"192140370","currency_domain_item_id":"17","posting_sta_ind":"Z2 ","is_overdraft_notice_dda_dflt":"Y","reference_nbr":"0","exception_desc":"NSF Posted (above the limit)","dda_default_decision":"Pay Item","is_omni_file":"N","display_flag":"Y","item_sequence_no":"190002236","approval_domain_item_id":null,"trans_dt":null}]}
```

The response I get after clicking the refresh or next button

```
{"total":32625,"transactions":[{"is_overdraft_fee":null,"dda_rej_cd_domain_item_id":null,"is_overdraft_fee_dda_dflt":null,"business_dt":"2013-07-03 00:00:00.0","booking_date":"2013-04-25","item_desc":"TBAAHB00000162","serial_no":"GFS130425017008","transaction_amt":"5,747.89","detailed_desc":null,"modified_by":"SYSTEM","posting_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice":null,"credit_debit_flag":"D","is_returnable":"N","modified_dt":"2013-07-02 22:39:10.0","transaction_code":"210","account_id":"6557428536","value_date":"2013-04-30","is_paperless":null,"bank_code":"875","transaction_id":"190640526","currency_domain_item_id":"0","posting_sta_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice_dda_dflt":null,"reference_nbr":"0","exception_desc":null,"dda_default_decision":null,"is_omni_file":null,"display_flag":"Y","item_sequence_no":"0","approval_domain_item_id":null,"trans_dt":null},{"is_overdraft_fee":null,"dda_rej_cd_domain_item_id":null,"is_overdraft_fee_dda_dflt":null,"business_dt":"2013-07-03 00:00:00.0","booking_date":"2013-04-25","item_desc":"HYHATB00000881","serial_no":"GFS130425016980","transaction_amt":"6,974.63","detailed_desc":null,"modified_by":"SYSTEM","posting_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice":null,"credit_debit_flag":"D","is_returnable":"N","modified_dt":"2013-07-02 22:39:10.0","transaction_code":"210","account_id":"6557428536","value_date":"2013-04-30","is_paperless":null,"bank_code":"875","transaction_id":"190640547","currency_domain_item_id":"0","posting_sta_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice_dda_dflt":null,"reference_nbr":"0","exception_desc":null,"dda_default_decision":null,"is_omni_file":null,"display_flag":"Y","item_sequence_no":"0","approval_domain_item_id":null,"trans_dt":null},{"is_overdraft_fee":null,"dda_rej_cd_domain_item_id":null,"is_overdraft_fee_dda_dflt":null,"business_dt":"2013-07-03 00:00:00.0","booking_date":"2013-04-25","item_desc":"TBAAHB00000160","serial_no":"GFS130425016995","transaction_amt":"10,500.00","detailed_desc":null,"modified_by":"SYSTEM","posting_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice":null,"credit_debit_flag":"D","is_returnable":"N","modified_dt":"2013-07-02 22:39:10.0","transaction_code":"210","account_id":"6557428536","value_date":"2013-04-30","is_paperless":null,"bank_code":"875","transaction_id":"190640548","currency_domain_item_id":"0","posting_sta_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice_dda_dflt":null,"reference_nbr":"0","exception_desc":null,"dda_default_decision":null,"is_omni_file":null,"display_flag":"Y","item_sequence_no":"0","approval_domain_item_id":null,"trans_dt":null},{"is_overdraft_fee":null,"dda_rej_cd_domain_item_id":null,"is_overdraft_fee_dda_dflt":null,"business_dt":"2013-07-03 00:00:00.0","booking_date":"2013-04-25","item_desc":"TBAAHB00000163","serial_no":"GFS130425016996","transaction_amt":"11,226.96","detailed_desc":null,"modified_by":"SYSTEM","posting_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice":null,"credit_debit_flag":"D","is_returnable":"N","modified_dt":"2013-07-02 22:39:10.0","transaction_code":"210","account_id":"6557428536","value_date":"2013-04-30","is_paperless":null,"bank_code":"875","transaction_id":"190640549","currency_domain_item_id":"0","posting_sta_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice_dda_dflt":null,"reference_nbr":"0","exception_desc":null,"dda_default_decision":null,"is_omni_file":null,"display_flag":"Y","item_sequence_no":"0","approval_domain_item_id":null,"trans_dt":null},{"is_overdraft_fee":null,"dda_rej_cd_domain_item_id":null,"is_overdraft_fee_dda_dflt":null,"business_dt":"2013-07-03 00:00:00.0","booking_date":"2013-04-25","item_desc":"TBAAHB00000169","serial_no":"GFS130425016999","transaction_amt":"21,986.00","detailed_desc":null,"modified_by":"SYSTEM","posting_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice":null,"credit_debit_flag":"D","is_returnable":"N","modified_dt":"2013-07-02 22:39:10.0","transaction_code":"210","account_id":"6557428536","value_date":"2013-04-30","is_paperless":null,"bank_code":"875","transaction_id":"190640550","currency_domain_item_id":"0","posting_sta_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice_dda_dflt":null,"reference_nbr":"0","exception_desc":null,"dda_default_decision":null,"is_omni_file":null,"display_flag":"Y","item_sequence_no":"0","approval_domain_item_id":null,"trans_dt":null},{"is_overdraft_fee":null,"dda_rej_cd_domain_item_id":null,"is_overdraft_fee_dda_dflt":null,"business_dt":"2013-07-03 00:00:00.0","booking_date":"2013-04-25","item_desc":"HYAATB00003162","serial_no":"GFS130425016979","transaction_amt":"22,606.00","detailed_desc":null,"modified_by":"SYSTEM","posting_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice":null,"credit_debit_flag":"D","is_returnable":"N","modified_dt":"2013-07-02 22:39:10.0","transaction_code":"210","account_id":"6557428536","value_date":"2013-04-30","is_paperless":null,"bank_code":"875","transaction_id":"190640551","currency_domain_item_id":"0","posting_sta_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice_dda_dflt":null,"reference_nbr":"0","exception_desc":null,"dda_default_decision":null,"is_omni_file":null,"display_flag":"Y","item_sequence_no":"0","approval_domain_item_id":null,"trans_dt":null},{"is_overdraft_fee":null,"dda_rej_cd_domain_item_id":null,"is_overdraft_fee_dda_dflt":null,"business_dt":"2013-07-03 00:00:00.0","booking_date":"2013-04-25","item_desc":"HYAATB00003168","serial_no":"GFS130425016976","transaction_amt":"22,901.88","detailed_desc":null,"modified_by":"SYSTEM","posting_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice":null,"credit_debit_flag":"D","is_returnable":"N","modified_dt":"2013-07-02 22:39:10.0","transaction_code":"210","account_id":"6557428536","value_date":"2013-04-30","is_paperless":null,"bank_code":"875","transaction_id":"190640552","currency_domain_item_id":"0","posting_sta_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice_dda_dflt":null,"reference_nbr":"0","exception_desc":null,"dda_default_decision":null,"is_omni_file":null,"display_flag":"Y","item_sequence_no":"0","approval_domain_item_id":null,"trans_dt":null},{"is_overdraft_fee":null,"dda_rej_cd_domain_item_id":null,"is_overdraft_fee_dda_dflt":null,"business_dt":"2013-07-03 00:00:00.0","booking_date":"2013-04-25","item_desc":"HYHATB00000876","serial_no":"GFS130425016986","transaction_amt":"25,078.04","detailed_desc":null,"modified_by":"SYSTEM","posting_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice":null,"credit_debit_flag":"D","is_returnable":"N","modified_dt":"2013-07-02 22:39:10.0","transaction_code":"210","account_id":"6557428536","value_date":"2013-04-30","is_paperless":null,"bank_code":"875","transaction_id":"190640553","currency_domain_item_id":"0","posting_sta_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice_dda_dflt":null,"reference_nbr":"0","exception_desc":null,"dda_default_decision":null,"is_omni_file":null,"display_flag":"Y","item_sequence_no":"0","approval_domain_item_id":null,"trans_dt":null},{"is_overdraft_fee":null,"dda_rej_cd_domain_item_id":null,"is_overdraft_fee_dda_dflt":null,"business_dt":"2013-07-03 00:00:00.0","booking_date":"2013-04-25","item_desc":"TBAAHB00000161","serial_no":"GFS130425017007","transaction_amt":"25,300.00","detailed_desc":null,"modified_by":"SYSTEM","posting_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice":null,"credit_debit_flag":"D","is_returnable":"N","modified_dt":"2013-07-02 22:39:10.0","transaction_code":"210","account_id":"6557428536","value_date":"2013-04-30","is_paperless":null,"bank_code":"875","transaction_id":"190640554","currency_domain_item_id":"0","posting_sta_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice_dda_dflt":null,"reference_nbr":"0","exception_desc":null,"dda_default_decision":null,"is_omni_file":null,"display_flag":"Y","item_sequence_no":"0","approval_domain_item_id":null,"trans_dt":null},{"is_overdraft_fee":null,"dda_rej_cd_domain_item_id":null,"is_overdraft_fee_dda_dflt":null,"business_dt":"2013-07-03 00:00:00.0","booking_date":"2013-04-25","item_desc":"TBAAHB00000170","serial_no":"GFS130425016992","transaction_amt":"25,785.35","detailed_desc":null,"modified_by":"SYSTEM","posting_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice":null,"credit_debit_flag":"D","is_returnable":"N","modified_dt":"2013-07-02 22:39:10.0","transaction_code":"210","account_id":"6557428536","value_date":"2013-04-30","is_paperless":null,"bank_code":"875","transaction_id":"190640555","currency_domain_item_id":"0","posting_sta_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice_dda_dflt":null,"reference_nbr":"0","exception_desc":null,"dda_default_decision":null,"is_omni_file":null,"display_flag":"Y","item_sequence_no":"0","approval_domain_item_id":null,"trans_dt":null},{"is_overdraft_fee":null,"dda_rej_cd_domain_item_id":null,"is_overdraft_fee_dda_dflt":null,"business_dt":"2013-07-03 00:00:00.0","booking_date":"2013-04-25","item_desc":"TBAAHB00000165","serial_no":"GFS130425017003","transaction_amt":"31,349.33","detailed_desc":null,"modified_by":"SYSTEM","posting_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice":null,"credit_debit_flag":"D","is_returnable":"N","modified_dt":"2013-07-02 22:39:10.0","transaction_code":"210","account_id":"6557428536","value_date":"2013-04-30","is_paperless":null,"bank_code":"875","transaction_id":"190640556","currency_domain_item_id":"0","posting_sta_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice_dda_dflt":null,"reference_nbr":"0","exception_desc":null,"dda_default_decision":null,"is_omni_file":null,"display_flag":"Y","item_sequence_no":"0","approval_domain_item_id":null,"trans_dt":null},{"is_overdraft_fee":null,"dda_rej_cd_domain_item_id":null,"is_overdraft_fee_dda_dflt":null,"business_dt":"2013-07-03 00:00:00.0","booking_date":"2013-04-25","item_desc":"TBAAHB00000164","serial_no":"GFS130425017001","transaction_amt":"64,600.00","detailed_desc":null,"modified_by":"SYSTEM","posting_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice":null,"credit_debit_flag":"D","is_returnable":"N","modified_dt":"2013-07-02 22:39:10.0","transaction_code":"210","account_id":"6557428536","value_date":"2013-04-30","is_paperless":null,"bank_code":"875","transaction_id":"190640557","currency_domain_item_id":"0","posting_sta_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice_dda_dflt":null,"reference_nbr":"0","exception_desc":null,"dda_default_decision":null,"is_omni_file":null,"display_flag":"Y","item_sequence_no":"0","approval_domain_item_id":null,"trans_dt":null},{"is_overdraft_fee":null,"dda_rej_cd_domain_item_id":null,"is_overdraft_fee_dda_dflt":null,"business_dt":"2013-07-03 00:00:00.0","booking_date":"2013-04-25","item_desc":"TBAAHB00000158","serial_no":"GFS130425016997","transaction_amt":"67,355.00","detailed_desc":null,"modified_by":"SYSTEM","posting_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice":null,"credit_debit_flag":"D","is_returnable":"N","modified_dt":"2013-07-02 22:39:10.0","transaction_code":"210","account_id":"6557428536","value_date":"2013-04-30","is_paperless":null,"bank_code":"875","transaction_id":"190640558","currency_domain_item_id":"0","posting_sta_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice_dda_dflt":null,"reference_nbr":"0","exception_desc":null,"dda_default_decision":null,"is_omni_file":null,"display_flag":"Y","item_sequence_no":"0","approval_domain_item_id":null,"trans_dt":null},{"is_overdraft_fee":null,"dda_rej_cd_domain_item_id":null,"is_overdraft_fee_dda_dflt":null,"business_dt":"2013-07-03 00:00:00.0","booking_date":"2013-04-25","item_desc":"TBAAHB00000151","serial_no":"GFS130425017009","transaction_amt":"71,814.92","detailed_desc":null,"modified_by":"SYSTEM","posting_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice":null,"credit_debit_flag":"D","is_returnable":"N","modified_dt":"2013-07-02 22:39:10.0","transaction_code":"210","account_id":"6557428536","value_date":"2013-04-30","is_paperless":null,"bank_code":"875","transaction_id":"190640559","currency_domain_item_id":"0","posting_sta_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice_dda_dflt":null,"reference_nbr":"0","exception_desc":null,"dda_default_decision":null,"is_omni_file":null,"display_flag":"Y","item_sequence_no":"0","approval_domain_item_id":null,"trans_dt":null},{"is_overdraft_fee":null,"dda_rej_cd_domain_item_id":null,"is_overdraft_fee_dda_dflt":null,"business_dt":"2013-07-03 00:00:00.0","booking_date":"2013-04-25","item_desc":"TBAAHB00000150","serial_no":"GFS130425017011","transaction_amt":"77,617.15","detailed_desc":null,"modified_by":"SYSTEM","posting_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice":null,"credit_debit_flag":"D","is_returnable":"N","modified_dt":"2013-07-02 22:39:10.0","transaction_code":"210","account_id":"6557428536","value_date":"2013-04-30","is_paperless":null,"bank_code":"875","transaction_id":"190640560","currency_domain_item_id":"0","posting_sta_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice_dda_dflt":null,"reference_nbr":"0","exception_desc":null,"dda_default_decision":null,"is_omni_file":null,"display_flag":"Y","item_sequence_no":"0","approval_domain_item_id":null,"trans_dt":null},{"is_overdraft_fee":null,"dda_rej_cd_domain_item_id":null,"is_overdraft_fee_dda_dflt":null,"business_dt":"2013-07-03 00:00:00.0","booking_date":"2013-04-25","item_desc":"TBAAHB00000157","serial_no":"GFS130425017000","transaction_amt":"80,000.00","detailed_desc":null,"modified_by":"SYSTEM","posting_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice":null,"credit_debit_flag":"D","is_returnable":"N","modified_dt":"2013-07-02 22:39:10.0","transaction_code":"210","account_id":"6557428536","value_date":"2013-04-30","is_paperless":null,"bank_code":"875","transaction_id":"190640561","currency_domain_item_id":"0","posting_sta_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice_dda_dflt":null,"reference_nbr":"0","exception_desc":null,"dda_default_decision":null,"is_omni_file":null,"display_flag":"Y","item_sequence_no":"0","approval_domain_item_id":null,"trans_dt":null},{"is_overdraft_fee":null,"dda_rej_cd_domain_item_id":null,"is_overdraft_fee_dda_dflt":null,"business_dt":"2013-07-03 00:00:00.0","booking_date":"2013-04-25","item_desc":"TBAAHB00000156","serial_no":"GFS130425017006","transaction_amt":"96,145.25","detailed_desc":null,"modified_by":"SYSTEM","posting_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice":null,"credit_debit_flag":"D","is_returnable":"N","modified_dt":"2013-07-02 22:39:10.0","transaction_code":"210","account_id":"6557428536","value_date":"2013-04-30","is_paperless":null,"bank_code":"875","transaction_id":"190640562","currency_domain_item_id":"0","posting_sta_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice_dda_dflt":null,"reference_nbr":"0","exception_desc":null,"dda_default_decision":null,"is_omni_file":null,"display_flag":"Y","item_sequence_no":"0","approval_domain_item_id":null,"trans_dt":null},{"is_overdraft_fee":null,"dda_rej_cd_domain_item_id":null,"is_overdraft_fee_dda_dflt":null,"business_dt":"2013-07-03 00:00:00.0","booking_date":"2013-04-25","item_desc":"TBAAHB00000166","serial_no":"GFS130425017002","transaction_amt":"97,072.65","detailed_desc":null,"modified_by":"SYSTEM","posting_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice":null,"credit_debit_flag":"D","is_returnable":"N","modified_dt":"2013-07-02 22:39:10.0","transaction_code":"210","account_id":"6557428536","value_date":"2013-04-30","is_paperless":null,"bank_code":"875","transaction_id":"190640563","currency_domain_item_id":"0","posting_sta_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice_dda_dflt":null,"reference_nbr":"0","exception_desc":null,"dda_default_decision":null,"is_omni_file":null,"display_flag":"Y","item_sequence_no":"0","approval_domain_item_id":null,"trans_dt":null},{"is_overdraft_fee":null,"dda_rej_cd_domain_item_id":null,"is_overdraft_fee_dda_dflt":null,"business_dt":"2013-07-03 00:00:00.0","booking_date":"2013-04-25","item_desc":"HYHATB00000882","serial_no":"GFS130425016981","transaction_amt":"115,823.68","detailed_desc":null,"modified_by":"SYSTEM","posting_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice":null,"credit_debit_flag":"D","is_returnable":"N","modified_dt":"2013-07-02 22:39:10.0","transaction_code":"210","account_id":"6557428536","value_date":"2013-04-30","is_paperless":null,"bank_code":"875","transaction_id":"190640564","currency_domain_item_id":"0","posting_sta_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice_dda_dflt":null,"reference_nbr":"0","exception_desc":null,"dda_default_decision":null,"is_omni_file":null,"display_flag":"Y","item_sequence_no":"0","approval_domain_item_id":null,"trans_dt":null},{"is_overdraft_fee":null,"dda_rej_cd_domain_item_id":null,"is_overdraft_fee_dda_dflt":null,"business_dt":"2013-07-03 00:00:00.0","booking_date":"2013-04-25","item_desc":"HYHATB00000878","serial_no":"GFS130425016982","transaction_amt":"119,989.00","detailed_desc":null,"modified_by":"SYSTEM","posting_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice":null,"credit_debit_flag":"D","is_returnable":"N","modified_dt":"2013-07-02 22:39:10.0","transaction_code":"210","account_id":"6557428536","value_date":"2013-04-30","is_paperless":null,"bank_code":"875","transaction_id":"190640565","currency_domain_item_id":"0","posting_sta_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice_dda_dflt":null,"reference_nbr":"0","exception_desc":null,"dda_default_decision":null,"is_omni_file":null,"display_flag":"Y","item_sequence_no":"0","approval_domain_item_id":null,"trans_dt":null},{"is_overdraft_fee":null,"dda_rej_cd_domain_item_id":null,"is_overdraft_fee_dda_dflt":null,"business_dt":"2013-07-03 00:00:00.0","booking_date":"2013-04-25","item_desc":"TBAAHB00000155","serial_no":"GFS130425017005","transaction_amt":"181,362.09","detailed_desc":null,"modified_by":"SYSTEM","posting_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice":null,"credit_debit_flag":"D","is_returnable":"N","modified_dt":"2013-07-02 22:39:10.0","transaction_code":"210","account_id":"6557428536","value_date":"2013-04-30","is_paperless":null,"bank_code":"875","transaction_id":"190640566","currency_domain_item_id":"0","posting_sta_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice_dda_dflt":null,"reference_nbr":"0","exception_desc":null,"dda_default_decision":null,"is_omni_file":null,"display_flag":"Y","item_sequence_no":"0","approval_domain_item_id":null,"trans_dt":null},{"is_overdraft_fee":null,"dda_rej_cd_domain_item_id":null,"is_overdraft_fee_dda_dflt":null,"business_dt":"2013-07-03 00:00:00.0","booking_date":"2013-04-25","item_desc":"TBAAHB00000154","serial_no":"GFS130425017004","transaction_amt":"292,500.00","detailed_desc":null,"modified_by":"SYSTEM","posting_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice":null,"credit_debit_flag":"D","is_returnable":"N","modified_dt":"2013-07-02 22:39:10.0","transaction_code":"210","account_id":"6557428536","value_date":"2013-04-30","is_paperless":null,"bank_code":"875","transaction_id":"190640587","currency_domain_item_id":"0","posting_sta_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice_dda_dflt":null,"reference_nbr":"0","exception_desc":null,"dda_default_decision":null,"is_omni_file":null,"display_flag":"Y","item_sequence_no":"0","approval_domain_item_id":null,"trans_dt":null},{"is_overdraft_fee":null,"dda_rej_cd_domain_item_id":null,"is_overdraft_fee_dda_dflt":null,"business_dt":"2013-07-03 00:00:00.0","booking_date":"2013-04-25","item_desc":"TBAAHB00000171","serial_no":"GFS130425016993","transaction_amt":"941,491.41","detailed_desc":null,"modified_by":"SYSTEM","posting_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice":null,"credit_debit_flag":"D","is_returnable":"N","modified_dt":"2013-07-02 22:39:10.0","transaction_code":"210","account_id":"6557428536","value_date":"2013-04-30","is_paperless":null,"bank_code":"875","transaction_id":"190640588","currency_domain_item_id":"0","posting_sta_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice_dda_dflt":null,"reference_nbr":"0","exception_desc":null,"dda_default_decision":null,"is_omni_file":null,"display_flag":"Y","item_sequence_no":"0","approval_domain_item_id":null,"trans_dt":null},{"is_overdraft_fee":null,"dda_rej_cd_domain_item_id":null,"is_overdraft_fee_dda_dflt":null,"business_dt":"2013-07-03 00:00:00.0","booking_date":"2013-04-25","item_desc":"BGGATS00002094","serial_no":"GFS1304250112317","transaction_amt":"47,854.16","detailed_desc":null,"modified_by":"SYSTEM","posting_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice":null,"credit_debit_flag":"C","is_returnable":"N","modified_dt":"2013-07-02 22:39:10.0","transaction_code":"246","account_id":"6557428536","value_date":"2013-04-30","is_paperless":null,"bank_code":"875","transaction_id":"190640589","currency_domain_item_id":"0","posting_sta_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice_dda_dflt":null,"reference_nbr":"0","exception_desc":null,"dda_default_decision":null,"is_omni_file":null,"display_flag":"Y","item_sequence_no":"0","approval_domain_item_id":null,"trans_dt":null},{"is_overdraft_fee":null,"dda_rej_cd_domain_item_id":null,"is_overdraft_fee_dda_dflt":null,"business_dt":"2013-07-03 00:00:00.0","booking_date":"2013-04-25","item_desc":"MIAUAS00057989","serial_no":"GFS1304250112300","transaction_amt":"46,695.49","detailed_desc":null,"modified_by":"SYSTEM","posting_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice":null,"credit_debit_flag":"C","is_returnable":"N","modified_dt":"2013-07-02 22:39:10.0","transaction_code":"246","account_id":"6557428536","value_date":"2013-04-30","is_paperless":null,"bank_code":"875","transaction_id":"190640590","currency_domain_item_id":"0","posting_sta_ind":null,"is_overdraft_notice_dda_dflt":null,"reference_nbr":"0","exception_desc":null,"dda_default_decision":null,"is_omni_file":null,"display_flag":"Y","item_sequence_no":"0","approval_domain_item_id":null,"trans_dt":null}]}
```

Comment: could you post so 1. response and the response after clicking next page that comes back from the server

Comment: It looks like the response you are getting back from the server has placed the total items number in the total pages number. Please add the response you are getting back to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your **update**:

The total count should not change, ever. When you get the next set of records the total should stay the same.

The reason your counter shows 657 is because your total is 32525 divided into 50 records per page will yield 657 pages.

---

Afte the last update try the following to set account ID:

```
store.getProxy().extraParams = {
    account_id: 12345
};
```

Comment: That shouldn't make any difference. It is already being set to the same store.

Comment: I need transactions that are made by a particular account id. Here, it returns the transactions for all the account ids

Comment: think you are loosing the account number when paging through the results. You can use extraParams to set that value so it does not get lost on subsequent server requests.

Answer (score 0):

Define a global variable called "filterParams"
and inside the transactionTabClick() function, set values for filterparams

`controller.filterparams = TasoDesktop.Util.authorize({
                account_id: record.get('account_number');`

and call another function for pagintoolbar "beforechange" event

```
fireChangeEvent: function() {
   controller.getTransactionsStore().getProxy().extraParams = controller.filterParams;}
```

(change the function according to your requirment)